# Rails 7, tailwind and view components, classes added to component not compiled / updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css, ruby-on-rails-7, view-components

I'm working on a Rails 7 project where I use [ViewComponents](https://viewcomponent.org) and [Tailwindcss](https://tailwindcss.com). I'm having some problem getting changes in component's `.html.erb` files to update properly.

When I run `./bin/dev` and make css-changes or additions inside `app/components/<module-name>/<file-name.html.erb` the added css class doesn't get compiled / rendered.

If I would add the same class in any of my `app/views` `html.erb` the correct styling is applied.

I have tried to update `config/tailwind.config.js` to include:

```
content: [
  ...
  './app/views/**/*',
  './app/components/**/*'
```

But every time I re-run `.bin/dev` the css-classes that only exists inside `app/components` won't show.

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: when you changed css on component views, is there css task `Rebuilding...` on your console ? any error ? and how you set the css classes, notice that `<%= css classes ... %>` could not work.

Comment: @LamPhan Thanks for your comment. Seems like you are correct about `<%= css classes ... %>`. If I add the classes directly, ex: `class="sm:col-span-4` it works, but if I have `class="<%= @col_span_classes %>` it doesn't. Any ideas why that is?

Comment: @LamPhan Found the problem here: https://github.com/rails/tailwindcss-rails/blob/main/README.md#class-names-must-be-spelled-out, and from this issue: https://github.com/rails/tailwindcss-rails/issues/127. Had a case where I constructed the class name like this: `class="sm:col-span-<%= @col_span %>"`. That didn't work since the classes needed to be spelled out. If I change the attribute value to be the full class name it worked, so `class="<%= @col_span_classes %>"` worked.

Answer (score 3):

I'm working with

```
gem 'view_component'
```

Based on what you did, I also updated my `config/tailwind.config.js` with the following and it worked for me with the following code:

```
content: [
    './public/*.html',
    './app/helpers/**/*.rb',
    './app/javascript/**/*.js',
    './app/views/**/*.{erb,haml,html,slim}',
    './app/components/**/*.{erb,haml,html,slim}' // I Add this line
 ],
```

Comment: For my components I'm dynamically updating the tailwind classes applied  in my component ruby files. Therefore I need to add `rb` to `./app/components` entry  as follows:
`'./app/components/**/*.{rb,erb,haml,html,slim}' // rb has been added `